# Integrate Amazon Chimes in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, amazon-chime

I am developing a game in Unity 3D which requires Amazon chime integration in it. However, I couldn't find any documentation for the same. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official Chime SDK available for Unity3D yet. May be what you can do is integrate Amazon Chime SDK in the different types of projects generated by Unity3D.
Since Amazon Chime SDK is available for iOS/Android/JavaScript(Browsers) You can integrate them in Unity generated projects for these platforms.